# NSDate accuracy when using the createdAt date from Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

In my app I need to get the dates of some objects from my Parse.com backend. For example the date on parse is: 2015-06-30T10:37:23.642Z.

I will use:

```
self.mostRecentMessageDate = object.createdAt;
```

Where mostRecentMessageDate is an NSDate object. However when I use NSLog to inspect the date I get 2015-06-30 10:37:23 +0000. It seems it has lost the precision of the milliseconds. Is this because of the way NSLog displays the date or do I need to do something to the NSDate object to make it more precise?

Any pointers on this would be great, thanks!

NOTE:

I need to do this because when I query for objects I use

```
[receivedMessagesQuery whereKey:@"createdAt" greaterThan:self.mostRecentMessageDate]; I want to make sure it isn't missing messages by ignoring the milliseconds part
```

Answer (score 2):

Whether the milliseconds are lost depends on Parse.com's way of transmitting the date (I have no experience with Parse.com).

`NSDate` omits the milliseconds when printing. If you rely on calculations with this precision, you can get a more precise value with `timeIntervalSince…` methods, like `timeIntervalSince1970`. These methods return an `NSTimeInterval` which is a `double`; the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/tdef/c:@T@NSTimeInterval) says this type *"yields sub-millisecond precision over a range of 10,000 years"* which should be precise enough for most purposes.

The `NSDate` comparison methods do take the milliseconds into account. You can easily test this:

```
NSDate *d1 = [NSDate date];
NSDate *d2 = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"%@ ?= %@ -- %d (%f, %f)", d1, d2, [d1 compare:d2], [d1 timeIntervalSince1970], [d2 timeIntervalSince1970]);

// Output:
// 2015-06-30 11:48:55 +0000 ?= 2015-06-30 11:48:55 +0000 -- -1 (1435664935.405415, 1435664935.405424)
// Note the "-1" here; if they were equal, it would be "0" instead.
```

Comment: Thanks for that, useful to know that NSDate does in fact compare milliseconds though I guess the question is if Parse does it or not. I'll have to look into it. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Beside DarkDust's answer you should think a little bit broader on it.

- Dates are akin of elapsed time from a staring point. They are represented as floating point numbers. It is not a good idea at all to compare floating point numbers on equality.
- The precision of instances of `NSDate` depends on many things. As mentioned by DarkDust, you do not know what parse delivers. Even inside Cocoa you get different precisions for `- initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:` and `-initWithTimeIntervalFromReferenceDate:`. To make things more complicated, if a date is stored and reread, you cannot predict, whether its precision changed. (I. e. Core Data reduces the precision.)

Do an epsilon check, i. e. as described [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/). (I did not check the content of the page.)

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll take a look at the epsilon check